# Help proving that $(n+a)^b = \Theta(n^b)$

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

Please you apologize me by my English.

I don't know how make that:
$$(n+a)^b = \Theta(n^b), b > 0$$
I know, I must to find two constants such that:
$$ c_{1} n^b \leq (n+a)^b \leq c_{2} n^b $$

I do not know what else to do. I'v tried with the Newton's binomial, but I'm lost.

Comment: What problem did you run into when using Newton's binomial?

Comment: Have you considered bounding $n+a$ above and below by a constant times $n$ (a constant that can possibly be dependent on $a,b$)? If you can do this you're set.

Comment: That: $(n+a)^b$

Comment: Please refrain from using "please," "help" and many "..." etc. Both in title and in body. Thank you.

Comment: Ok... I'm sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $a \geq 0$ then

$$(n+0)^b \leq (n+a)^b \,,$$

thus $c_1=1$ works.

Also, for all $n \geq a$ you have

$$(n+a)^b \leq (2n)^b =2^b n^b \,.$$

Now, fixing

$$c_2 = \max \{ 2^b, \frac{(n+1)^b}{n^b},...,  \frac{(n+n-1)^b}{n^b} \}$$

you get the desired inequality.

For $a \leq 0$ you can get the inequlities the other way around, excepting that you'll have an issue if $a$ is a negative integer (what happens if $n=-a$?).

Answer (score 1):

Here, $(n+a)^{b} = n^{b}
 + a^{b}
 + ... \geq
 n^{b}
  \Longrightarrow
 (n+a)^{b}
 = \Omega
 (n^{b}
 ),$

$ Also, by  \space definition, f(n) = O (g(n)), n \rightarrow
 \infty
 \Longrightarrow
 |f(n)| \leq
  M(g(n)) $

$ As \space n \rightarrow
 \infty
 (n >> a), (n + a) \leq
  2n $

$(n+a)^{b}
 \leq(2n)^{b}\leq k*n^{b}\Longrightarrow
 (n+a)^{b}
 = O
 (n^{b}
 ), $

$Since (n+a)^{b}
 = \Omega
 (n^{b}
 ), and (n+a)^{b}
 = O
 (n^{b}
 ),$

$\Longrightarrow(n+a)^{b}
 = \Theta
 (n^{b}
 )$

Answer (score 0):

For the upper bound,
$(n+a)^b = n^b(1+a/n)^b
$. 
If $n/a > b$,  $(1+a/n)^b < (1+1/b)^b < e$,
so we can take $c_2 = e$ for large enough $n$.

By taking $n$ large enough compared to $a$ and $b$,
we can take any value greater than 1 for $c_2$.

Answer (score -1):

I proved it using the binomial expansion , which is

(x+y)n=nC0xny0+nC1xn−1y1+nC2xn−2y2+......nCnx0yn
now for the above problem (n+a)b=bC0nba0+nC1nb−1a1+nC2nb−2a2+......nCnn0an

we also now that for any polynomial
a0x1+a1x2+a2x2+⋯+anxn≤(a0+a1+a2+⋯+an)xn

substituting bC0a0
with C0, bC1a1 with C1

and so on (because that is a constant) we would get

(n+a)b=C0nb+C1nb−1+C2nb−2+......Cnn0

now i would jump to the following conclusion

C0nb≤C0nb+C1nb−1+C2nb−2+......Cnn0≤(C0+C1+C2+......Cn)nb

which makes (n+a)b=θ(nb)

Comment: You do realize that this is a 4 years old question, with 3 more answers, among which an accepted one, do you?